# ios iphone UITextField events

Tags: iphone, ios, events, uitextfield

I have a UITextField in the event calls a function EditingDidEnd A to validate the contents of the field, then I have a button that calls a function B by passing the contents of text field and then brings me to another view which shows the results . The issue is that if the text field is empty by giving the button brings me to the view of results and then shows me the error that the field is empty ... :) Typical rookie with the theme events ... What you suggest I use? Exit on I put a function that validates for not following that execution??!

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do your validation when the button is pressed

```
-(void)buttonNextClicked:(id)sender
{
     if(!self.textField.text || [self.textField.text isEqualToString:@""])
     {
          // Show an alert with validation message
          return;
     }

     //Proceed with the new view
}
```

If you want to validate as soon as the editing has stopped make a method for validation and call it in the both places

```
-(BOOL)isInputTextValid:(NSString *)txt
{
    if(!txt)
       return NO;
    if([txt isEqualToString:@""])
       return NO;
    if(other_invalid_values)
       return NO;

    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Hello, I do the validation when I press the button but the alert message shows me the following view instead of the current view

Comment: Post your code, you are obviously showing the other view even if your validation fails...

Comment: `-(IBAction)validaNumero:(id)sender{
    
    continua = YES;
    
    Utils *util = [[Utils alloc]init];   
    NSString *alerta;
    
    //si el campo esta en blanco no contiunua
    if([util enBlanco:sender])
    {
        continua=NO;
        alerta=@"El campo no puede estar en blanco";
        
    }
    
    //mostramos una alerta
    if (!continua) {
        UIAlertView *alert;
        alert=[util mensajeError:@"Ojito!" msg:alerta];
        [alert show];        
    } 

    }
    
    -(IBAction)done:(id)sender
{
    if (!continua) {
        return;
    } `

Comment: Edit your question and put it there

Comment: Thanks I have clarified a few concepts.

Answer (score 0):

Simply check for the empty text in your delegate method and do nothing if it is empty.

```
if (!textField.text || [textField.text isEqualToString:@""])
   return;
```

Comment: Hello, I do the validation when I press the button but the alert message shows me the following view instead of the current view

Comment: Thanks I have clarified a few concepts.

Comment: Great - make sure you tick the check mark if this answer helped you.